# Append character to beginning of each new line in Apple Numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, iwork-numbers

Ive got cells with the following data, each ingredient for a recipe is in a new line in the same cell. I need to add a pipe | at the beginning of each line but not the first. Is it possible to do this in Excel or Numbers?

**Current Cell 1**

```
2 tablespoons almond flour
1/2 tablespoon coconut flour
1 scoop  ‘Vanilla’ Collagen
1/4 tsp;  baking powder
1 large whole egg
1 tbsp;melted butter or ghee
1 tbsp;frozen wild blueberries
```

**Changed Cell 1**

```
2 tablespoons almond flour
|1/2 tablespoon coconut flour
|1 scoop  ‘Vanilla’ Collagen
|1/4 tsp;  baking powder
|1 large whole egg
|1 tbsp;melted butter or ghee
|1 tbsp;frozen wild blueberries
```

Answer (score 1):

Ive found a solution, identify a new line with the following `\n` and then replace with `\n |`

[image]